# Returning Dictionary From templatetags and Printing in template

Tags: django, templates, templatetags

I am trying to **return most voted answer** for each question.also i want to send also extra infomation of that answer like **vote and id**.

Printing one value is easy but for more than one i have to return dictionary.So how can i return dictionary and print all values in template.

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

    @register.simple_tag
    def getmostvotedanswer(answers):
        answer = answers.order_by('-vote')[0]
        answer_info = {
            'answer':answer.answer,
            'vote':answer.vote,
            'id':answer.id
        }
        return answer_info
```

**index.html**

```html
<p class="small text-muted ">{% getmostvotedanswer question.answer_set.all %}</p>
```

**Output**

```
{'answer': 'THIS IS ANSWER THIS IS ANSWER THIS IS ANSWER THIS IS ANSWER THIS IS ANSWER', 'vote': 7, 'id': 1}
```

I can call template_tag 3 times for three values.

But I don't want to call templatetag again and again i think it will affect performance.

**view.py**

```
def index(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    context = {
        'questions':questions
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context=context)
```

Edit -> Add view.py

Comment: Why do you use template tags? More easy and debugable to send cook data on view before to send it to template.

Comment: @daniherrera it can't be possible because i do reverse relationship in template.For one question there can be multiple answers but on home page i wanna show only highest voted answer.Thats why i am sending questions using View and getting top voted answer using templatetag

Comment: What means 'top voted' ? 3? 10?

Comment: @daniherrera most voted sir

Comment: Does my answer solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest, debugable, best performance and test friendly way to achieve it is to cook data on view instead of write custom template tag. Windows functions are needed to get the first answer of each question:

```
from django.db.models import F, Window
from django.db.models.functions.window import FirstValue

def index(request):

    #q_and_a_ids = [ (id question, id most voted answer), (... ]
    q_and_a_ids = (
      Question
      .objects
      .annotate(
        most_voted_id=Window(
          expression=FirstValue('answer__id'),
          partition_by=['id'],
          order_by=F('answer__vote').desc()
        )
       )
      .distinct()
      .values_list( 'id', 'most_voted_id')
    )

    answers_ids = set( [ a_id for (_,a_id) in q_and_a_ids] )

    questions_dict = Question.objects.in_bulk()
    answers_dict = Answers.objects.filter(pk__in=answers_ids).in_bulk()

    #q_and_a = [ { 'q':question, 'a':most voted answer}, { ... ]
    q_and_a = [ {'q': questions_dict[q_id],
                 'a': answers_dict.get(a_id) } 
                 for (q_id,a_id) in q_and_a_ids ]

    context = {
        'questions_and_answers': q_and_a
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have overcomplicated this.

```
answer = answers.order_by('-vote')[0]
    answer_info = {
        'answer':answer.answer,
        'vote':answer.vote,
        'id':answer.id
    }
```

Looking at your code above, I get that vote and id are properties of answer object. So it is unnecessary to use answer info dictionary.
You can use below code.

```
@register.simple_tag
def getmostvotedanswer(answers):
    answer = answers.order_by('-vote')[0]
    
    return answer
```

Because returned answer is the actual object accessed in template. So it contains all the answers properties like id, vote ect.

To access these values use below code.

```
<p class="small text-muted ">{% getmostvotedanswer question.answer_set.all as most_voted %}{{ most_voted.answer }} {{ most_voted.id }} {{ most_voted.vote }} </p>
```